# Wordpress how to insert new post data to a new table

Tags: wordpress

i want to insert some data from posts to my new table in database.
how can I do that?
I'm new to wordpress and their functions so please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: From the `wp_posts` table?

Comment: no i made a new table in the wordpress database called users_posts

Comment: You can use mysql insert query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 


$wpdb->insert('table_own', array(table_y=>$_POST['y'])
```

Comment: forgot to close the } But i can't add it:S